# Nominatim: search by doornumber and postalcode

Tags: nominatim

Is there a way I can search in nominatim by postalcode and door number?

For example when I search by:

```
https://my-api.com/geo/search.php?q=243 1507EM&format=json&addressdetails=1&extratags=1
```

I am not getting the desired address back.

Or when I do something like the following:

```
https://my-api.com/geo/search.php?street=243 &postalcode=1507EM&format=json&addressdetails=1&extratags=1
```

I am getting the postalcode area back but not the exact house / coordinates.

Comment: From your examples, I don't see a full address, only **street=243** . You should also be url encoding the address data

Comment: [link]https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Examples

Comment: see the title of my question. im looking for a way to do this without streetname.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that any geo api can do this since supplying only a door number and postal code could essentially return many  results depending on the population size of the area, or none at all.

Comment: ok thanks. would it then be possible to query the postalcode and get all the addresses related to it?